# In python how to add a string to a list so it will show up in an array as a value

Tags: python, arrays

I need help getting self.url into labels array as a value.

In python, the array is a list and the description is a string:

`self.url = base_url + post['title']['commandLink']`

```
    labels = list(util.extract_all_keys(post, 'text'))`

    self.info = {'labels': labels}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you just need to use [list.append](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable):

```
self.url = base_url + post['title']['commandLink']
labels = list(util.extract_all_keys(post, 'text'))
labels.append(self.url)
```

... and your string `self.url` is a value in the `labels` list.